# Why am I unable to change style methods with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to change the css of an element using Jquery. I am able to access the element, and use basic effects such as .show() and .hide(), but for some reason .addclass() or .css() are both not working for me.

My relevant code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const $newQuote = $('#new-quote');
  const $quoteBox = $('#quote-box');

  $newQuote.on('click', () => {
    $('#quote-box').css('color', 'purple');
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="quote-box">
    <div class="quote-text">
      <span id="text">???</span>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button" id="new-quote">New quote</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this does not work, but for some reason the following JQuery does work:

```js
    $(document).ready(() => {
  const $newQuote = $('#new-quote');
  const $quoteBox = $('#quote-box');

  $newQuote.on('click', () => {
    $quoteBox.hide();
  })
})
```

Could someone please shed some light on why .css() or .addclass() are not working for me?

Comment: I added the HTML to your snippet and it works as intended.

Comment: what HTML did you add?

Comment: I moved the HTML from outside the snippet to inside. Click on the "edited" line to see the changes.

Comment: so why would it work here, but not on my end in vs code? Sorry if this seems like an arbitrary question, I am new to jquery and am trying to get over this hurdle.

Comment: Maybe you have CSS that's overriding it with `!important`.

Comment: Try `$quoteBox.css('color', 'purple');` instead

Comment: I appreciate the help, but unfortunately this doesnt resolve my issue

Comment: why do you have a span inside your div? maybe that span element has some color already. What you're changing is the div's color (not the span's color, even if it can inherit it if no color is defined). I'd get rid of that span. The simpler, the better... OR, I'd try to change the span's element color instead.